# Why isn't youtube_dl woking in my PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm, youtube-dl

```
import youtube_dl

youtube_dl 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9pzm5b6FFY'
```

I have tried this code. But all I get is a syntax error.

Comment: the way you are trying to call wont work as thats the `cli` way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the YoutubeDL class, try:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl    
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to do something like

```
import os

os.system("youtube_dl 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9pzm5b6FFY' ")
```

this call will be `blocking`.

Comment: Or they could use https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl